# How can I get center location on maps v2 on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to search for center the location in my *Android* application,

I am using *Android Google Maps v2*.

I know that I can get the *lat* and *long* for screen top, left after using `Projection.fromScreenLocation`, but how can I determine the center location?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to use `googleMap.getCameraPosition().target`

for more info see http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#target

Answer (score -2):

Mr.Lee, Korean.

First, you will have to read [this Android official guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Second, please get the sample code refered to that document above from [Here in the Android Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code)

Third, You can find what you want to know in the sample code as follows;

```
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // if "false", MyLocation Button disappears.

}
```

Finally, please read [this good tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/) and you will get a good help.

For more information about Google Maps API ve, please contact me who live in Seoul.