# How to get the users location and zoom in upon loading maps Android V2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I can display the map and have the button show on the map, when I tap it it does exactly what I want it to do. In my code I have this:

```
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getMyLocation();
```

Is there a way to do this automatically upon loading the map, without having to tap the zoom into location button?

I researched this and found examples on getting the users location, but the examples I found didn't do what I wanted, I am not sure it was code for V2 maps. Surely there must be an easy, code minimal way to do this by now?

I read through [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338955/how-can-i-get-center-location-on-maps-v2-on-android) post on Stackoverflow, but I have no idea what to do with this code:

```
googleMap.getCameraPosition().target
```

target takes a location I think?

Any assistance is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using the following code:

```
   lm =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();

    towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);

    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    if(location != null){

        Double glat = location.getLatitude();
        Double glon = location.getLongitude();

    }
```

Then setting the map up:

```
CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(glat, glon))
        .zoom(15)
        .build();     
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
```

This get the users location, and when the map loads, it automatically zooms into that location, where you should see a blue dot where you sit!